# How to post to LogStash installed on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash

(ELK noob) I have ELK installed in an Azure VM. Kibana is up and running and I can see `syslogs`.

I have tried opening the port `9200` (`az vm open-port --port 9200 --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyELK`) to be able to log to LogStash directly, but I am not sure how to do this. Should LogStash respond to HTTP requests on port 9200?

Is it possible to `curl` a request just to test? I have tried but without response from LS.

Comment: yeah, if you open port on the VM (firewall\iptables\whatever) and on the NSG it will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LogStash responds to HTTP on port 9200. If you don’t open the port 9200, all the HTTP REST will block by the NSG associated with the VM.

**First**, make sure that your open the port in firewall.

**Second**, in your Azure VM overview, select Networking in the left, and find what is your Network Security Group name. Just like follow picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji2Ro.png)

**Third**, if you open the port in portal, you can select the your NSG and add an Inbound rule to open port 9200. If you want to use Azure CLI, after you login Azure CLI, use the command *“ az vm open-port –port 9200 –resource-group MyResourceGroup –name MyELK –nsg=name NSG_name “*, if you also have another NSG, open the port again with the right NSG name.

If your want to know more about Network Security Group, please click [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview)

Comment: How come I can reach Kibana by simply opening a port (no NSG)? Anyways, this does not work.. first of all it´s `--port`, not `-port` and the -`nsg=...` will only return `az: error: unrecognized arguments: –nsg=name ELKNSG`.

Comment: It's my fault, it should be '--nsg-name'. If the Kibana works regularly in the Azure VM? And if you open all the port that Kibana need in Azure VM firewall(if the firewall is open), especially port 9200? If all above is OK, you could check inbound and outbound rules of NSG, if the port you need actually opened.